# DB error when a new user registers after server migration

Tags: members, solspace-user, registration

Just moved the site from a lamp to IIS. We are using Solspace's User module for registration but we are getting the following DB

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1366

Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'last_activity' at row 1

INSERT INTO `exp_members` (
`group_id`, 
`username`, 
`password`, 
`salt`, 
`ip_address`, 
`unique_id`, 
`join_date`, 
`email`, 
`screen_name`, 
`time_format`, 
`url`, 
`location`, 
`occupation`, 
`interests`, 
`language`, 
`last_activity`, 
`bday_d`, 
`bday_m`, 
`bday_y`, 
`aol_im`, 
`yahoo_im`, 
`msn_im`, 
`icq`, 
`bio`, 
`profile_views`, 
`timezone`, 
`signature`

)VALUES (

'6', 
'ashby', '63fd27cab8beb2c3fbf8aca6d49f71a333ab71c3a741d8fd3bd6627698696b1fa4dc63ece5143a06a8701081f0a64b3fea9da59a181b770c5876a4454e9610cb', 'CzO6TFy\'#l=<`G@BSjl?AEa*W[Y0N3bcr4).O:;@j^:+Bds&4wM:)*\\w,m!ziRC~sp\".o-m1.qZTR?TeK,JhmCut;j', 
'190.140.68.177', 
'a6444108bf453435e0b71f60ea11e4b640403178', 
1425070565, 
'email@gmail.com', 
'ashby', 
'', 
'', 
'', 
'', 
'', 
'', 
'', 
'', 
'', 
'', 
'', 
'', 
'', 
'', 
'', 
'', 
'', 
'')

Filename: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\codeigniter\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely not using the latest version of User: a separate conversation mentioned that you were using `3.4.5`, and the latest as of this writing is `3.5.2`. Please update User to the latest version.